# AWS Cloudformation error: Transform AWS::LanguageExtensions failed with: Fn::ForEach layout is incorrect

Tags: loops, foreach, aws-cloudformation

I have a script that creates nested objects. I would like to loop through these objects and create resources in a CloudFormation template. The script dynamically generates object strings, and there is a possibility that, for example, the "pAccountIds4" object (as shown below) might not exist. In such cases, I would like to conditionally check for the presence of objects other than the first one, "pAccountIds1."

However, in the CloudFormation templates, I am encountering the following error: "Transform AWS::LanguageExtensions failed with: Fn::ForEach collection must be a list of strings" I am unsure how to resolve this error.

Here is an example of my objects:

```json
{
    "Parameters": {
        "pAccountIds1": "886180295749,169278231308,888561797329,316900773169",
        "pAccountIds2": "776321084004,404626256571,598611764315,325462626455,",
        "pAccountIds3": "388805547470,169282815852,117009268289,124665313191",
        "pAccountIds4": "543887508227,146967747421,198623621466,316135323942"
    }
}
```

And here is my template:

```yaml
---
Transform: 'AWS::LanguageExtensions'
###
## Parameters
Parameters:
  pAccountIds1:
    Description: First 100 list of member account ids to grant CloudTrail log access.
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
  pAccountIds2:
    Description: Second 100 of member account ids to grant CloudTrail log access.
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Default: ""
  pAccountIds3:
    Description: Third 100 of member account ids to grant CloudTrail log access.
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Default: ""
  pAccountIds4:
    Description: Fourth 100 of member account ids to grant CloudTrail log access.
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Default: ""
  pDatabaseName:
    Type: String
    Default: 'amazon_security_lake_glue_db_eu_west_1'
  pCloudtrailTableName:
    Type: String
    Default: 'amazon_security_lake_table_eu_west_1_cloud_trail_mgmt_1_0'


OutputName:
  Description: The name of the output
  Value: pAccountIds1
###
## Resources
Resources:
  'Fn::ForEach::CloudTrailShares':
    - AccountId
    - [!Ref pAccountIds1, !Ref pAccountIds2, !Ref pAccountIds3, !Ref pAccountIds4]
    - 'CloudTrailFilter${AccountId}':
        Type: AWS::LakeFormation::DataCellsFilter
        Properties:
          TableCatalogId: !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
          DatabaseName: !Ref pDatabaseName
          TableName: !Ref pCloudtrailTableName
          Name: !Join ['_', ['cloudtrail', !Ref AccountId]]
          RowFilter:
            FilterExpression: !Sub "accountid='${AccountId}'"
          ColumnWildcard: {}
      'CloudTrailPermission${AccountId}':
        Type: AWS::LakeFormation::PrincipalPermissions
        Properties:
          Principal:
            DataLakePrincipalIdentifier: !Ref AccountId
          Permissions: ['SELECT']
          PermissionsWithGrantOption: ['SELECT']
          Resource:
            DataCellsFilter:
              TableCatalogId: !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
              Name: !Select
                      - 3
                      - !Split
                        - '|'
                        - !Ref
                            Fn::Sub: 'CloudTrailFilter${AccountId}'
              TableName: !Ref pCloudtrailTableName
              DatabaseName: !Ref pDatabaseName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for `Fn::Foreach`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-foreach.html) describes the second parameter as (emphasis mine):

> The collection of values to iterate over. This can be an array in this parameter, **or** it can be a Ref to a CommaDelimitedList.

What you are providing is this:

```yaml
[!Ref pAccountIds1, !Ref pAccountIds2, !Ref pAccountIds3, !Ref pAccountIds4]
```

Because *each* of `pAccountIds1`, `pAccountIds2`, `pAccountIds3`, and `pAccountIds4` is a `CommaDelimitedList`, what you have is a *list of lists*, as though you'd written this:

```yaml
[
   [ "886180295749","169278231308","888561797329","316900773169" ],
   [ "776321084004","404626256571","598611764315","325462626455" ],
   [ "388805547470","169282815852","117009268289","124665313191" ],
   [ "543887508227","146967747421","198623621466","316135323942" ]
]
```

The error is saying that it must instead be a *list of strings*:

```yaml
[
   "886180295749","169278231308","888561797329","316900773169","776321084004",
   "404626256571","598611764315","325462626455","388805547470","169282815852",
   "117009268289","124665313191","543887508227","146967747421","198623621466",
   "316135323942"
]
```

In other words, the first value of `AccountId` in the loop should be `"886180295749"`, but you are providing `[ "886180295749","169278231308","888561797329","316900773169" ]`.

I can think of two ways to solve this:

1. Put all your account IDs into a single `CommaDelimitedList` parameter. Then when you reference it as `- !Ref pAccountIds` CloudFormation will expand it to a list of strings. (Important: do *not* write `- [!Ref pAccountIds]` - that's still a list with a list inside it.)
2. Keep the separate parameters, but as strings. Then combine them into one longer string, and split *that whole long string* into a single list, as in the example below:

```yaml
'Fn::ForEach::CloudTrailShares':
  - AccountId
  - !Split [",", 
      !Join [",", 
        [!Ref pAccountIds1, !Ref pAccountIds2, !Ref pAccountIds3, !Ref pAccountIds4]
      ]
    ]
  - ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. but I am still getting this error:

Transform AWS::LanguageExtensions failed with: Type mismatch for parameter /pAccountIds1 on resource Fn::ForEach::CloudtrailShares.forEach

Comment: Your solution doesn’t work. It throws me error

Comment: @Krisna OK, so it's now giving a slightly different error? Have you tried both my suggestions? Do they both give exactly the same error as each other?

Comment: Good morning!

Yes I have tried both suggestion, The error is same error: Transform AWS::LanguageExtensions failed with: Type mismatch for parameter /pAccountIds1 on resource Fn::ForEach::CloudtrailShares.forEach.

Comment: I have changed type from CommaDelimitedList to String. Seems like it's working. Don't know why it does not work with CommaDelimitedList.

Comment: Apparently it does not allow empty string that's why I was this error